# Ant <import ... /> basedir is not a directory?

Tags: java, xml, ant

I'm trying to import an ant xml file from different folder tree and I get the following error:

```
/product/sbm_master/checkout/git/commonartifacts/anttask/lib.xml:48: Basedir /product/sbm_master/checkout/git/commonartifacts/anttask/lib.xml is not a directory
```

This is the importing part:

```
<import file="${commonartifacts.svn.checkout.dir}/anttask/lib.xml" optional="true"/>
```

I don't get it, does it matter where xml file is located in order to import it?

Thanks

Comment: you should check your working directory.If lib.xml is located on working directory be sure that directory exists in working directory, if it isn't located on working directory then you have to write full directory.If it is windows begin from disk name like C:\ or ../../product or if it is linux begin from / or ../../

Comment: Thanks for reply Serkhan, it is not in working directory and I provide full path. It's linux. The path is correct, already verified

Comment: Use include instead: < include file="${commonartifacts.svn.checkout.dir}/anttask/lib.xml"/>

Comment: Hi Hussam, thanks, I tried that but same result :/